# Uninstalled Mongovue by mistake and looking for license file

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I uninstalled MongoVue by mistake.

I was attempting to move the license from my old PC to a new PC.

I went into license manager but there was nothing useful there, I then clicked uninstall expecting a menu but there was no menu.

The guy who purchased the license has left and I can't find the details.

Does anyone know if the license is still on my PC somewhere and where I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the license file, it takes the form:

order-33xxxxxx.license

The license file is not stored in Program Files, so if you uninstall by mistake, you'll need to find the original license file.

Easiest option is to search your PC using: order*.license

Answer (score 1):

I could no longer find my license file as my companies email policy has since purged it and tried for a long time finding it on the pc and couldn't. I really love this program and I can't get to the company to ask them to move it. I was moving to a new work PC and needed to move my data over (win7 to win10).

Here is what I did and it worked (your mileage may vary, some of these folders may be hidden):

1. Copy the folder in program files to the new machine

   C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoVUE\MongoVUE 1.6.9
2. Copy your AppData to new machine (connections.xml file mainly):

   C:\Users\user_login\AppData\Local\MongoVUE
3. export the registry key in old machine (regedit):

   Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MongoVUE\License

When exporting the registration file, name it something.reg (it will look like name: "data", Type: "REG_BINARY", Data: random_value) This is your license data as the name suggests.

4. import the key in the new system with regedit.
5. create a shortcut to the "*C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoVUE\MongoVUE 1.6.9\MongoVUE.exe*" in:

   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MongoVUE

Should work like nothing happened. Worked for me at least.